# Autocompletion in sublimetext3

Tags: python, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I'm totally unfamiliar with SublimeText3 and want to code in python with this editor.
I'm used to autocompleting my code with the tab touch. It usually proposes every function possible with the package it's associated with. It is very useful.
However, on a sublime text, it only displays function already used before. \

[the illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0pJL.png%5C)

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env 
import matplotlib.pypot as plt
import numpy as np

if __name__ == "__main__":

print("hello world")

A = np.linespace
np.
```

How can I improve that manage the autocompletion tool to work efficiently?
Merci d'avance

Comment: I get the full autocompletion after typing the dot after np. - no tab or anything needed. Try upgrading to the latest version sublime text 4 (was released a couple days ago i think). Besides that you can check if autocompletion is enabled in the preferences, which should be by default (preferences > settings, on the right tab you have your applied settings, on the left side are the default ones) ("auto_complete": true,).

Comment: How lucky you are, did you install SublimeREPL or anything else?

Comment: No, just standard Sublime Text. Did you save your file as a .py file? Is Python selected under Tools > Build Systems?

Comment: Actually, i think i understood wrong - i do not get the full list after typing the dot after np., just after entering the first letter of the desired function (e.g. np.s shows me sine functions etc)

Comment: Maybe try Kite for Sublime Text: https://www.kite.com/integrations/sublime-text/

Comment: Thanks, after reading again, I think my question may not describe correctly the problem.